# Bootstrap 3 modal overlay background color and animation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, overlay

I'm having some issues changing the background color when the Modal Window is displayed using Bootstrap 3.

Ideally I want it to be more of a black and tone down the opacity a bit, but when you click on the boxes located here;

http://roblb.devour.org/march2014/index%20copy.html

Also - how do I stop the Modal sliding down? I just want it to fade in? I've seen a few items on here, but none of them actually answer this...

Thanks

Rob

Comment: I've just found out that if i add a color to the following style; .modal {background-color:black;} this sets the background color. However, I'm still stuck with the modal sliding down...

Answer (score 14):

To change the backdrop color you can use this:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

or separate into clases:

```
.modal-blue .modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.modal-white .modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

and then add the class to your div:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-white" ... >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      ...
  </div>
</div>
```

to stop sliding down remove the "fade" class.

Hope this help,

regards.

Answer (score 2):

Easy remedy is to override the default.
Just use:

```
.fade.in {
   background: #000; // or whatever you like
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used :

```
.modal {
  background-color:black;
}
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
We can also try below pattern. 

    .modal-content
    {
       background-color: #331a00;
       color: #b3c6ff;
    }

    .modal-content h5{  
       color: #ffcc00;
    }

    .close{
       color: #cf3834;
    }

    .modal-content button{
       background-color: #ffcc00;
       color: #cf3834;
    }
```